# How I can change "Figs. 1 and 3" to "Figs. 1 et 3"?

Tags: cleveref

In this example, how can I customize `\cref{fig:1,fig:3}`? I.e instead of having `(Figs. 1 and 3)`, I would like to have `(Figs. 1 et 3)`. The same question with `\Cref{fig:1,fig:3}`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalise]{cleveref}

\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\caption{Missing figure 1.}\label{fig:1}
\caption{Missing figure 2.}\label{fig:2}
\caption{Missing figure 3.}\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}

\obeylines 
Single figure: \cref{fig:2}
Two figures: \cref{fig:1,fig:3}
Range of consecutive figures: \cref{fig:1,fig:2,fig:3}, \crefrange{fig:1}{fig:3}

\vspace{.5cm}

Single figure: \Cref{fig:2}
Two figures: \Cref{fig:1,fig:3}
Range of consecutive figures: \Cref{fig:1,fig:2,fig:3}, \Crefrange{fig:1}{fig:3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your document language French, Latin, or something else? (`et` means `and` in both French and Latin...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the macro `\crefpairconjunction`. Specifically, run

```
\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ et }
```

after loading `cleveref`.

See also p. 13 of the [user guide](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) of the `cleveref` package.

Comment: in relation to the same subject, how to have:

\cref{tab:1} gives: Tab. 1    and    
\Cref{tab:1} gives: Tableau 1

Comment: I found on page 14 the commands: \crefname{table}{Tab.}{Tabs.} and \Crefname{table}{Tableau}{Tableaux}

Comment: @simo If you adopt my solution these names don't have to be adjusted manually at all.

Comment: I have not adobted your solution Alan Munn (which is simple and practical) because I want to keep the abbreviations Fig.  Figs.  Tab. and Tabs. Thank you so much for your contribution.

Comment: @simo - To keep the names `Fig.`, `Figs.`, `Tab.`, and `Tabs.` while also specifying the language option `french`, all you'd need to do is issue the instructions `\crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}`, `\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}`, \crefname{table}{Tab.}{Tabs.}`, and `\Crefname{table}{Tab.}{Tabs.}`.

Comment: @Mico, exactly, your solution is relevant. Thank you

Comment: @Mico- two small problems when I apply the different solutions on my thesis document 1) latex does not accept two points (:) in labels 2) when I use the french option in the usepackage{cleveref}, the compilation takes a lot of time. These problems do not appear in this example.

Comment: @simo - Did you try Alan Munn's solution, viz. `\usepackage[french,shorthands=!;?]{babel}`? Of course, this makes `:` non-special, which may not be acceptable. If that's the case, the only solution is not to use `:` anywhere in the arguments of  `\label` and `\cref`.

Comment: @Mico: even with Alan's solution, the problem persists. Fortunately, I usually use `-` in the labels instead of `:`. I used `:` only 7 times.

Answer (score 13):

The `cleveref` package is `babel`-aware, so it suffices to load `babel` and add `french` to the `cleveref` options.  In this example I've turned off the `:` shorthand defined for French because your labels have `:` in them.

In fact the use of `babel` isn't actually needed for this to work, you can simply pass the `french` option to `cleveref` and the French conjunction will be used.

When used this way, `cleveref` will also adjust the names of the relevant elements correctly (*Tableau(x)* etc.).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[french,shorthands=!;?]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalise,french]{cleveref}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\caption{Missing figure 1.}\label{fig:1}
\caption{Missing figure 2.}\label{fig:2}
\caption{Missing figure 3.}\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}

\obeylines 
Single figure: \cref{fig:2}
Two figures: \cref{fig:1,fig:3}
Range of consecutive figures: \cref{fig:1,fig:2,fig:3}, \crefrange{fig:1}{fig:3}

\vspace{.5cm}

Single figure: \Cref{fig:2}
Two figures: \Cref{fig:1,fig:3}
Range of consecutive figures: \Cref{fig:1,fig:2,fig:3}, \Crefrange{fig:1}{fig:3}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Your write-up may create the impression that `cleveref` employs the `babel` package if the option `french` is set. That's not the case: `cleveref` has its own set of language-specific rules, which get executed whether or not `babel` is loaded.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. The documentation isn't clear on how they interact. So the solution is even simpler: just add `french` to the `cleveref` options.

Comment: `cleveref` does interact with `babel`. I guess @Mico is right to say that if only french is required, if the option is passed to `cleveref` in the absence of `babel` it will work as expected. But if two languages are employed in the document, `cleveref` will adapt to `\foreignlanguage` (or equivalent) accordingly, then requiring `babel`.

Comment: @gusbrs - The OP hasn't indicated whether he/she uses `babel` or `polyglossia` and which language(s) are used in the document. (French is of course a distinct possibility, but so is Latin...) `cleveref` cooperates with ("interacts"?) with both `babel` and `polyglossia`.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much for all your contributions, now I can say I got a satisfactory result:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalise]{cleveref}

\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ et }
\crefname{table}{Tab.}{Tabs.}
\Crefname{table}{Tableau}{Tableaux}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\caption{Missing figure 1.}\label{fig:1}
\caption{Missing figure 2.}\label{fig:2}
\caption{Missing figure 3.}\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}
%=================   
\begin{table}
   \caption{Exemple d'environnement table 1}  \label{tab1}
   \caption{Exemple d'environnement table 2}  \label{tab2}   
   \caption{Exemple d'environnement table 2}  \label{tab3}
\end{table}
%=================

\obeylines % just for this example
Single figure: \cref{fig:2}
Two figures: \cref{fig:1,fig:3}
Range of consecutive figures: \cref{fig:1,fig:2,fig:3}, \crefrange{fig:1}{fig:3}

\vspace{.5cm}

Single figure: \Cref{fig:2}
Two figures: \Cref{fig:1,fig:3}
Range of consecutive figures: \Cref{fig:1,fig:2,fig:3}, \Crefrange{fig:1}fig:3}

\vspace{.5cm}

Single table: \cref{tab1} ; \Cref{tab1}
Two figures: \cref{tab1,tab2}  ; \Cref{tab1,tab2}
Range of consecutive figures: \cref{tab1,tab2,tab3}, \Crefrange{tab1}{tab3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since this doesn't add anything to the answers already here, it's not really needed as an answer.  See [Should I self answer my question?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2667/2693) for some discussion.

Comment: @Alan Munn: In my answer I tried to complete the solution of Mico, to have the same thing with the tables.